# Total Row Count for Grouped Values in SSRS 2008

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, dynamics-crm-2011

I have a report that displays names of all accounts and activities performed under each of them.

AccountName: ABC Corp
Activity: Installation

I want to group the AccountName and get the total number of Activities performed for each account.

ABC Corp: 1

How can I accomplish this in SSRS 2008? I am able to group the AccountName but I need a way to convert the Activity column to int so I can get the total.

Help appreciated!

Comment: The grouping worked fine in the development instance but broke in production. Again, to specify the problem:

Comment: The grouping worked fine in the development instance but broke in production. Again, to specify the problem: I need to run a report to show the total number of activities performed by resources on each account. I grouped the Account column and put in this expression in the expression field: CountRows("Account"). This gave me the total number of Activities for that Account. Now, I have the total number value in the Account column and names of Activities in the Activity column. I simply changed the column name to Activity Total. This is the column that contained number of activities. Not working

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can add a total row for the Account group and give your total field the expression **`CountRows("AccountGroupName")`**, to count the Activity detail rows for each Account group.

You can also put the total value at the level of the group row / group header.

More details about Function `CountRows` could be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156330(v=sql.100).aspx

Answer (score 6):

You can put `CountRows()` in an expression within a group and it will show the row count for each grouping.